# How to use QtSingleApplication to active app in front of other window?

Tags: qt, qml

I use QtSingleApplication to make my qml app to be a single instance app.
However, I can't active app in front of other window.

I use the latest QtSingleApplication code from github and below is my main method:

```
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtQml>
#include <QtSingleApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QtSingleApplication app(argc, argv);
    if (app.isRunning())
    {
        // I think I should do something here
        return 0;
    }

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/qml/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

How to implement it or other way to implement single instance app perfectly with qml?
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

main.cpp

```
 QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

        QObject* qmlObject = engine.rootObjects().at(0);
        WindowsPlatformSpecific wps(qmlObject);

        QObject::connect(&app, SIGNAL(messageReceived(const QString&)),
                     &wps, SLOT(handleMessage(const QString&)));
```

//////////////////////

```
 void WindowsPlatformSpecific::handleMessage(const QString& message)
    {
        QObject* pp = this->parent();
        QWindow* pWnd = qobject_cast<QWindow*>(pp);

        if (!pWnd)
            qInfo() <<"The winId is null";

        WId winId = pWnd->winId();
        SetForegroundWindowByWId(winId);
    }
```

/////////////////////////

```
bool WindowsPlatformSpecific::SetForegroundWindowByWId(WId winId)
{
    HWND hWnd = (HWND)winId;
    if ( hWnd )
    {
        ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

        WINDOWINFO wi;
    GetWindowInfo(hWnd, &wi);
    bool bTopMost = ((wi.dwExStyle & WS_EX_TOPMOST) == WS_EX_TOPMOST);

    SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE);

    if (!bTopMost)
    {
        SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_NOTOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE);
    }

    SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);

    return true;
    }

    return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

No, `isRunning()` indicates that the program is already running another instance, so this instance should just exit again.

You need to send a message to the running instance and it has to bring itself forward.

See https://github.com/qtproject/qt-solutions/blob/master/qtsingleapplication/examples/loader/main.cpp

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it doesn't work. Because I use the QML instead of the QWidgt. I can't set the activeWindows so that I can't active the app on front of other windows.

Comment: You mean you can't use the activation window helper method, but you can still react to the message and activate the window yourself. `QWindow::requestActivate()` for example